# assign vector at x, y coordinates of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, variable-assignment

I am moving from MATLAB to R and have a question regarding how to assign a vector at `x`, `y` coordinates of a matrix. For this, I tried with defining an array and then reading each pixel. I am stuck with reassigning values to the matrix after processing it. Following is my code:

```
GR_anom<-array(NaN,dim=c(180,360,100))
for (i in 1:180)) {
  for (j in 1:360) {
    GR_vec<-as.data.frame(GR[i,j,,drop=TRUE])
    Nonses= seasonaltrend(GR_vec,2002,2017)
    GR_anom[i,j,] <- Nonses[1]
  }
}
```

The `line(GR_anom[i,j,] <- Nonses[1])` is written in the MATLAB format but in R it seems to work differently. I am stuck here since long in it, can you please suggest?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without a sample of `GR`. At the very least, it seems unlikely that `GR[i,j,,drop = TRUE]` should be a data frame. But whether it should be an array, a matrix, or a vector... can't tell with the information you've provided. And what does `Nonses` look like? `seasonaltrend` isn't a built-in R function, so I don't know. If it's a list, or a data frame, or a matrix, then `[1]` may need to be `[[1]]` or `[1, ]` or `[, 1]`, or something else.

Comment: Your question is about matrix assignment. You could make a much simpler example without GR, `seasonaltrend()`, lower dimensions, etc. Consider something simple like `mat <- [...] ; vec <- [...] ; mat[1,1] <- vec` and don't forget to state what you expect. You may actually solve your problem while preparing such an example!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem. The issue was the variable 'Nonses' is a list and therefore cannot be assigned to an array. In matlab everything is a matrix, so didn't think in that direction. Thank you very much for your responses.